# Git commit aborts before I can create a commit message and I use "--wait"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I use Visual Studio Code on my Mac as my text editor and have it set up to open a new window to type my commit message, however when I type 'git commit' in the terminal, it instantaneously displays

> Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

I have my git config set up as `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`,  and when I type `git config --global -e`, it shows

> [core] editor = code --wait

I've uninstalled and reinstalled git, and I've went through the [VS Code as Git Editor setup guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-editor), and have searched online for a solution for at least ten hours. My git and VS Code versions are up to date and my commits do work when I type `git commit -m "message here"` in the command line, but I still don't know why my VS Code editor option isn't working.

Any ideas here? Thank you!

Comment: I know nothing about this `code` editor, but you can test its behavior on the command line yourself, from a bash shell: run `code --wait <somefile>` and see if it really does wait for you to edit that file. If it doesn't, find some alternative form of the command that does, or whatever setting there might be in `code` to make it actually wait, or whatever. (When bash runs a command, it lets the command run to completion, then prints another `$` prompt, or whatever you have the prompt set to.)

Comment: @torek the OP wants to use Visual Studio Code. I’ve seen people set the environment variable $EDITOR with `code —wait` which works.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to edit my environment variables by typing `open .bash_profile` in the terminal and sure enough, my default didn't have the `--wait` flag on it. I'm attaching a screenshot for visual people. Thanks @evolutionxbox for the idea!

[Screenshot of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP8Gv.png)